# Pandas Merge Results in larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, rows

I have two dataframes without duplicated values and with the same number of rows. After left merge, I still get a dataframe with more rows. What am I missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something like this:

```
mergedfield = pd.merge(dataFrame1, dataFrame2, on ='value', how ="left")
```